# Isn't the decision that this question is opinion based itself an answer to this question?

Tags: discussion, answers

I asked [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/49801/how-is-someone-supposed-to-know-their-own-varna-especially-with-evil-shapeshift) question on how is someone supposed to know their own varna. It got closed because it was deemed opinion based.

However, is the decision that this question is opinion based not an answer to the question itself? If the methods used to classify your own varna are based on opinion, you cannot be sure you are right. Thus, it is best to not list your own varna and let other people decide for themselves based on your actions. Surely the people who deemed this is opinion based should show how they came to this conclusion as an answer, because it would answer the question (as no you cannot be sure).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "*the decision that this question is opinion based*" is *"itself an answer to this question*".

But notice that it s "*an*" answer.

The problem with the question isn't that there isn't *an* answer; it's that there are potentially *many* answers, most of them different.

The closers aren't claiming that this question has no answer, nor are they claiming that the answer implied by the closure is the only correct answer.

Their concern is that there will be many answers, all expressing the varying opinions of the individuals that wrote them.

Had the question asked for explicit scripture related to the underlying original question, it wouldn't have been soliciting opinion, and I doubt it would have been closed.

Comment: Any opinion-based answers will end up effectively being the exact same answer as the closure answer, as it means you cannot be sure. Sure the answerer may not realise that, but that's not here or there.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa, suppose one answer is "*Eat 7 eggs for breakfast every day for 7 months, and at the end you will understand. That is the only method that works.*", and another answer is "*Run around your house 7 times every morning for 7 months, and at the end you will understand.  That is the only method that works.*". Both are answers to the question, neither is the same as the closure answer, and at most one of them can be true. ¶ The point of the closure is to avoid nonsense like that.

Comment: With those answers, the answerers do not really know if they are right. There is nothing in scripture backing them up. Their lack of a reference itself proves they do not really know, proving there is no actual way of knowing to us and the real answer is you cannot be sure as there is no way to know.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa said "*There is nothing in scripture backing them up.*".  Exactly.  As I already said: "*Had the question asked for explicit scripture related to the underlying original question, it wouldn't have been soliciting opinion, and I doubt it would have been closed.*".